# In R, multiply columns by matching columns from another dataframe, when the second dataframe has only one row

Tags: r, dataframe, data-analysis

df1 has many rows with Symbol, df2 has only one row. How can I multiply all matching df1 rows to the df2 row and create a separate df3 with all newly calculated values including  Symbol from df1?

The data looks like this ( please note that this is a very shrinked illustration, df1 has over 300 columns and df2 about 50)
DF1

```
Symbol  GR MF        Effic MF     Ale
TRUE    1.320005832 -0.080712181  .25445
ABC     .65                       .32
Z                    .22
```

DF2

```
GR MF        Effic MF
1           10
```

I have tried this code, but it doesn't generate any results.

```
df3 <-  df1[names(df1) %in% names(df2)] <- sapply(
  names(df1[names(df1) %in% names(df2)]), 
  function(x) df1[[x]] * df2[[x]]
)
```

I expect it the final file to have Symbol and all multiplications.

```
Symbol  GR MF        Effic MF       
TRUE    1.320005832 -0.80712181
ABC     .65                        
Z                    2.2
```

Comment: It seems like a key point of the problem is that `DF1` has multiple rows - perhaps you could add 1 or 2 more rows to your `DF1` sample data to better reflect reality?

Comment: That said, I think something like this should work: `df3 = df1; cols = intersect(names(df3), names(df2)); df3[cols] = df3[cols] * df2[cols]`.

Comment: @Gregor, thank you for your suggestions. I have added more data. Tried your solution but getting the following error: Error in Ops.data.frame(df3[cols], df2[cols]) : 
  ‘*’ only defined for equally-sized data frames

Comment: Okay, modify the last bit to `df3[cols] = df3[cols] * df2[rep(1, nrow(df3)), cols]`

Comment: it creates one column with df2 values: GR MF,  Effic MF etc, but not per df1 Symbol

Comment: Hi @Vito K, Welcome to Stack!  If you want to easily include more lines of your ```DF1``` and ```DF2``` dataframes, you can use ```dput``` and ```head``` like this:```dput(head(DF1,10))``` to get the first 10 lines (modify 10 to the number of your choice if you want to include more/less) and then include that output in your question above. That will give others more data to work with as well.

Comment: Yeah - I can't reproduce. And I can't easily import your data as its shared (the blanks make it especially difficult. `dput()` would make it especially easy). For a toy example, `mt = mtcars[1:5, 1:3]`, `mt1 = mtcars[1, 2:3]`, this method seems to work well: `result = mt; result[, 2:3] = result[, 2:3] * mt1[rep(1, nrow(result)), ]`

Comment: @RussThomas Thanks for you suggestion, but with that number of columns, it will not be beneficial to post it. The way I describe gives a good description how the data looks like. Thanks again.

Comment: @Gregor I have too many columns to specify them.

Comment: @Vito K, try this in your dput command to just select the columns you want to include: ```dput(head(DF1[c("Symbol", "GR MF", "Effic MF", "Ale")],10))```. Double check the spelling of the column names as I took them from your above example.

Comment: If that still looks too big Vito, try `dput(droplevels(DF1[1:5, 1:4]))` to give the first 5 rows of the first 4 columns.